# Left Bit shift and casting

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a behaviour that i don't understand, i try to construct an 64 integer from an array of bytes from big endian to little endian.

```
uint64_t u;
uint8_t bytes[2];


bytes[1] = 0xFF;
u =  bytes[1] << 24 ;
dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, 8 );
```

00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF

```
u =  ( (uint16_t) bytes[1]) << 24 ;
dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, 8 );
```

00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF

```
u =  ( (uint32_t) bytes[1]) << 24 ;
dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, 8 );
```

00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00

I don't understand why it give me the correct result only if i cast to a type that has more bits than the shift size. I have tried different values :

- 0xFF-1 give the same bad result
- **100 give correct result without casting**

So i wanted to know what is the rule ? and why 100 give me the correct value.

Thank you.

Edit :

Here is a reproductible example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


void dump_bytes_as_hex( uint8_t* b, int count )
{
    FILE* f;

    f = stdout;

    for( int c = 0; c < count; ++c )
    {
        fprintf( f, "%02X", b[c] );
        fputc( ' ', f );
    }
    fputc( '\n', f );
    fflush( f );
}

void test( uint8_t i )
{
    uint64_t u;
    uint8_t bytes[2];

    fprintf( stdout, "Test with %d\n", (int) i );

    u = 0;
    bytes[1] = i;

    u =  bytes[1] << 24 ;
    dump_bytes_as_hex( (uint8_t*) &u, 8 );

    u =  ( (uint16_t) bytes[1]) << 24 ;
    dump_bytes_as_hex( (uint8_t*) &u, 8 );

    u =  ( (uint32_t) bytes[1]) << 24 ;
    dump_bytes_as_hex( (uint8_t*) &u, 8 );

    fprintf( stdout, "\n\n");
}



int main()
{

    test( 0xFF );
    test( 0xFF -1  );
    test( 100 );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I presume that `dump_bytes_as_hex` is showing l.s. byte first. In the examples the value will be promoted to `int` and shifting a signed value can lead to trouble. Even when you cast to `uint16_t` that will be promoted to (signed) `int` before shifting.

Comment: You're _not_ showing the code for `dump_bytes_as_hex`, but ... Why are you doing: `dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, 8 );`? Why not use: `dump_bytes_as_hex(bytes, sizeof(bytes));`?

Comment: @Craig Estey, You mean `dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, sizeof(u) )`?

Comment: @ikegami No, that was OP's code that I just copied (i.e. _OP_ used `8`). I'm _not_ trying to correct the `&u` call that way.

Comment: I have updated the question with a reproductible example.

Comment: Tip: `dump_bytes_as_hex` could be replaced with `printf( "%" PRIx32 "\n", u );` (You'll also need to include `inttypes.h`.)

Comment: @Craig Estey, Then you're wrong. It should be `dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, sizeof(u) )`, not `dump_bytes_as_hex(bytes, sizeof(bytes))`. They're trying to dump `u`, not `bytes`.

Comment: @ikegami As I mentioned, we _needed_ to see the code for `dump_bytes_as_hex`  [before we should comment further]. They're trying to dump `u` but, IMO, that's wrong. With the edit, the dump function is dumping a byte stream. And, dumping `bytes` is more useful generally as the `u` code only handles a single instance in a larger buffer (e.g. 1000 bytes).

Comment: @Craig Estey, Then it only works if the object has type `uint64_t`. It's not a bug to use a general purpose function. And seeing that your version silently gives the wrong output if you pass a `uint32_t`, one could argue your solution is worse.

Comment: Re "*dumping bytes is more useful generally*", The OP is trying to debug the shifting. Dumping a variable other than the one you want to examine is not "more useful generally".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So i wanted to know what is the rule ?

In fact there is no rule for your specific examples ...

> ```
> bytes[1] = 0xFF;
> u =  bytes[1] << 24 ;
> ```

... and ...

> ```
> u =  ( (uint16_t) bytes[1]) << 24 ;
> dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, 8 );
> ```

... in the event that your `int` is 32 bits wide.

The left operand of a shift operation is is subject to *the usual arithmetic conversions*, which will have the effect of converting the 8- or 16-bit unsigned value of the left operand to (`signed`) `int` and producing a result of that type.  If the arithmetic result of a left shift of a value of signed type (*i.e.* `int`) is not representable as a value of that type then **the behavior is undefined**.  That is the case here (which is why I said there is no rule).

In your particular case, it appears that your implementation is performing the shift as if by reinterpreting the left operand as an unsigned 32-bit value, the reinterpreting the result as a (signed) int.  The assignment to type `uint64_t` then proceeds (normally) by converting the negative right operand to ty `uint64_t` by adding 2<sup>64</sup> to bring it into the range of that type.  (Such conversions are performed only for conversion to unsigned integer types, not to signed ones.)  You are working on a little-endian system and printing out the resulting bytes in memory order, so you get:

> 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF

On the other hand, if you convert the shift operand to `uint32_t` on your 32-0bit system, ...

> ```
> u =  ( (uint32_t) bytes[1]) << 24 ;
> dump_bytes_as_hex( &u, 8 );
> ```

... then the resulting type is unaffected by the standard arithmetic conversions, and the result of the conversion has that type.  `uint32_t` can represent the arithmetic result of the shift (`0xff000000`), so that is in fact the result.  That value is unchanged when converted to type `uint64_t` for the assignment.

---

General advice: use unsigned types when working with bitwise operations, and especially when performing shifts.

Comment: Re "*General advice: use unsigned types when working with bitwise operations*", It's hard. On a system with 64-bit ints, your solution uses a signed type.

Comment: @ikegami, none of the code in this answer is *my* solution.  All snippets are quoted from the question.  Personally, I might be inclined to say that implementations having `int` narrower than 32 bits are not supported, and then use `unsigned int` instead of `uint32_t`.  Or since `uint64_t` is the target type anyway, it might be even better to use that from the get-go.  Yes, it does take some attention to choose the right types, but that in no way contradicts my advice.

Comment: This isn't actually "the usual arithmetic conversions" which would come with a "balancing" between the operands. Instead shift operators have a special rule "The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand." So something like `my_char << 8ULL` will still result in a a promotion of the left operand to `int` and the result will be `int`.

Comment: Thank you, i have understanded your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable to which you assign the result, if any, is irrelevant.

It only works if the type of the left-hand operand is a type that, after integer promotion, can hold the result.

- `(uint8_t)0xFF << 24`

  In an environment with an `int` type of 16..32 bits, `(uint8_t)0xFF` is promoted to an `int`. 0xFF × 2<sup>24</sup> is too large to hold in an `int`. Being a signed type, this results in undefined behaviour.

  In an environment with an `int` type of 33+ bits, `(uint8_t)0xFF` is promoted to an `int`. 0xFF × 2<sup>24</sup> fits in an `int`. This works.
- `(uint16_t)0xFF << 24`

  In an environment with an `int` type of 16..24 bits, `(uint16_t)0xFF` results in a 16-bit `unsigned int`. Left-shifting by an amount of bits greater than or equal to the size of the operand is undefined behaviour.

  In an environment with an `int` type of 25..32 bits, `(uint16_t)0xFF` results in an `int`. 0xFF × 2<sup>24</sup> is too large to hold in an `int`. Being a signed type, this results in undefined behaviour.

  In an environment with an `int` type of 33+ bits, `(uint16_t)0xFF` results in an `int`. 0xFF × 2<sup>24</sup> fits in an `int`. This works.
- `(uint32_t)0xFF << 24`

  0xFF × 2<sup>24</sup> fits in a 32-bit unsigned integer. This works.

So, to produce a `uint64_t`, you want

```c
(uint64_t)( (uint64_t)u8 << 24 )
```

or

```c
(uint64_t)( (uint32_t)u8 << 24 )
```

However, the outer cast can be dropped here since the assignment will implicitly perform this cast.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answered me.